# Changing navbar background-color depending of the page

Tags: angularjs

Being new to angular, I am trying to achieve the following :

Change the `background-color` of my navbar when I am scrolling in my homepage, and let it to a fixed `background-color` when I am on the other pages.

To achieve the following, I created a `scroll` directive like the following :

```
app.directive("scroll", function ($window,$location) {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
      angular.element($window).bind("scroll", function() {          
        if (this.pageYOffset > 0) {
          scope.backgroundCol = "black";
        } else {
          scope.backgroundCol = "transparent";
        }
        scope.$apply();
      });
    };
});
```

I was thinking of checking the `location` in this directive, and if the `location` is different from my homepage, then I would fix a `background-color` to my navbar. Is there a more logic and cleaner way to achieve what I want to do?

Answer (score 0):

A good way to do it would be to use `ng-controller`, along with `$location`.

For example:

```
<div ng-controller="homepageController">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default" ng-class="{ navbar-custom: isHomepage('/')}">
  </nav>
</div>
```

and in the controller:

```
function homepageController($scope, $location)  { 
    $scope.isHomepage = function (currentLocation) { 
        return currentLocation === $location.path();
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `ui-router` the best way is to use the `isState` filter :

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" ng-class="{'navbar-custom': ('app.home' | isState)}"></nav>
```

This way, you don't have to create anything in your controller to check if you're on the right page.